# Magento 2: Dynamically update custom options (percentage) price

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options

I am working with a simple product with custom options.

I am updating the base price of the simple product with custom logic (height and width inputs). This is working fine.

Now here comes my problem. If I add a custom option with `Price Type = Percent`, this is calculated of the old base price (before my update), not the new base price.

**Example.**

The Baseprice of the simple product = **100**

Custom options look like this:

[image]

This gives me a price of the custom options as **10 (10% of 100)** and **20 (20% of 100)**.
But since the product page has loaded initially, the base price has changed to 150, and I would like to show **15 (10% of 150)** and **30 (20% of 150)**.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?